# AmCharts - how to load external CSV data for force-directed tree?

Tags: javascript, csv, amcharts, amcharts4

Using this example: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-tree/
What would CSV file look like?
For line graph it looks easy as described in this example:
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data/#CSV_example
But what about that tree graph where you have "children"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is not mentioned in the docs anywhere, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1312) on Github.

A maintainer replied:

> Answering your question: no, you can't load hierarchical data from CSV.

Therefore, unfortunately, unless you want to create a single-level tree you can't load CSV data for it. You can only use JSON.